# Iff condition for $A_1\times A_2 \times A_3 \times\cdots $ being countable, $\forall i$ $A_i \subseteq \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to find and prove an if and only if condition for:

$A_1\times A_2 \times A_3 \times \cdots $

Being a countable set, given that for all $i$ $A_i \subseteq \mathbb N$

Any tips on what the condition could be?

(For countability in this case it is meant there is a bijection from naturals to the set, or that it is finite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the condition is that only a finite number of the $A_i$ have more than one element, or one of the $A_i$ is empty. If there are an infinite number of $A_i$ with at least two elements, and all $A_i $ are nonempty, then the cartesian product is uncountable. This can be shown using something akin to Cantor's diagonal argument. If there is only a finite number of $A_i$ with more than one element, then the cartesian product is countable.

Comment: Not necessary. If one of the $A_i$ is empty, then the product is empty.

Comment: @edm Ah, I forgot about that case. Thank you. I will edit my answer.

Comment: It should be "have no more than one element". I can't edit this, please edit yourself.

Comment: @edm Thanks again. It's easy to get confused with the wording.